# Abstract methods in an abstract class constructor: design flaw?

Tags: java, oop

I have an abstract class `Entity`. Every class extending `Entity` will need some default and some customizable setup:

```
public abstract class Entity {

    protected Entity() {
        // ... default setup
        customSetup();
    }

    protected abstract void customSetup();
    // ...
}
```

My extending class `MyEntity` takes a parameter in the constructor, that will be used in `customSetup()`:

```
public class MyEntity extends Entity {

    private Data data;

    public MyEntity(Data d) {
        super(); // in here customSetup() is called!
        data = d;
    }

    @Override
    protected void customSetup() {
        codeDependingOn(data); // will throw NPE: data==null yet!
    }
}
```

As comments state, this code won't work.

I could just throw away `customSetup()` and put all the custom code after `super()`, but having that abstract method makes clearer what you're supposed to put there.

I feel like I'm violating some rule of OOP design. What's the correct way to do what I want?

Comment: Some / many people make the case that you should not call any non-final method from a constructor for the very reason Malcolm stated.

Comment: Is customSetup() ever going to be called after the object is constructed?  Why not just add the codeDependingOn(data) to your constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

Comment: @AndrewC: no, that's why I put it in the constructor. I just wanted to "encapsulate" the custom part of the setup. Thank you all for the help, I didn't know about that rule, but I've learned it the right way :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is generally a bad idea to call methods which can be overriden from a constructor. The problem is that the class is not yet fully initialized, and when the method is called in a subclass, it may cause trouble.

Take a look at this question: [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors), it has a good explanation.

Comment: that's just what happened. so, should I just rethink the whole design?

Comment: `customSetup()` must definitely be called after all the superclass and the current class constructors have run. Constructors don't work with overridable methods well, this is the part you should rethink.